# Chrome Notification API (for Extensions!) How to Re-enable Once Blocked?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I have spent considerable time researching this and hopefully I have just missed something so I thought I would bounce it off the StackExchange community as well.

Background:

On latest Chrome > 65, all of the notifications are stores on a per-site basis, so if one were to grant or deny notification popup for a SITE and want to reverse that decision (accidentally clicked the "block" for example) they can simply go into Chrome notification settings, find that specific site, and remove the block.  This works as designed today and is well documented.

So here is the issue detail in a scenario:

Now, that exact same mechanism is used for extensions.  An extension is initially granted all it's required permissions and works properly.  Then, the user accidentally clicks "block" one time on a single desktop notification from the extension using the "gears" cog-wheel icon on the notification which then changes the notify balloon to this prompt:

[image: https://i.imgur.com/f7Rp0B1.png]

Now, any time that extension attempts to send a notify message, instead of the normal desktop notify, an ugly javascript notify pops up in the middle of the screen (with the exact same notify text), and two buttons - "OK" and "Cancel".  All extension functionality is unchanged if "OK" is clicked for example, the very same functions fire as if the user had clicked the prior desktop notify balloon popup.

Here are two screenshots of this exact scenario using the popular Tampermonkey Chrome extension (using a randomly selected script with a known update) that uses desktop notification API to communicate script updates:

"Normal" desktop notify message with default grant permission:

[image: https://i.imgur.com/JLn9y1c.png]

The exact same message (appears in center of the screen) once that permission is revoked by user clicking "block". **Note the actual message itself is not blocked which I find odd, just the desktop notify GUI bubble:

[image: https://i.imgur.com/yR31pos.png]

So, the question is really 2-fold:

1. Where does Chrome store that boolean value of PermissionLevel FOR EXTENSIONS - as they do NOT appear in the normal list of granted/blocked SITES.  If not in the UI, is this setting exposed in a configuration file or is there even currently any way in Chrome>65 for the user to ever reverse this decision?
2. Is there either a programmatic method that can be implemented by an extension developer on the back-end to ever check if this has occurred and re-prompt the user to change their mind and re-grant that permission?  I have found a couple unofficial posts here saying common sense says no to avoid malicious harassing of users etc. but I cannot find anything official.

Comment: I've tried blocking an extension that uses **chrome.notifications API** via that chrome://settings page but I don't see it being applied: the notifications show up anyway. AFAICT it was always exempt from the policy. Judging by the [source code](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/chrome/browser/notifications/notifier_state_tracker.cc?l=111&rcl=b53b29c27fe6d4b22015471b614a669b35b654f3) it can be blocked only via master [preferences/policies](https://www.chromium.org/administrators/configuring-other-preferences).

Comment: I don't understand your comment.  The screenshots above are literally from live systems showing the block takes place, and the effect which is absolutely real.  On that system, there is literally NO WAY to reenable desktop notify for that extension.  So again, the question is, once blocked it seems there is no way specifically on extensions/apps exposed to unblock unless you can perhaps point me to a config file or GUI setting I'm missing?  TIA!

Comment: I've also gone as far as to test this using two new FLAGS:

#enable-message-center-new-style-notifications, and #enable-native-notifications, which has had no effect on exposing any way to re-enable blocked/denied desktop notify for an extension

Comment: I was talking about standard UI notifications which don't have that block/unblock functionality at all. I can only see it if I explicitly enable new style notifications via chrome://flags/#enable-message-center-new-style-notification. Since it's experimental, I guess they just didn't implement the feature entirely.

Comment: Exactly.  Thanks so much for digging into the code though too!  I had cross-posted this also over in the Google groups and also not a single workaround there so sounds like we are correct I went ahead and opened a Chromium issue over at:  https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=825497  for anyone else that is experiencing this to STAR/comment there to hopefully at least get it assigned!  I'll leave it open here though just to welcome and S.O. workaround ideas in the meantime and also help steer others impacted to the appropriate issue #.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I can confirm after opening this as an official Chromium bug, that it's sitting waiting for triage and clearly has no current workaround here:

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=825497

I also did further testing to determine you can use the ID from the extension and add it into "sites" settings which also based on that behavior, appears to be yet another bug due to some settings not saving, none having desired effect, etc.

I will post this as the current answer as of 04-09-2018:

"it is impossible to re-enable Chrome desktop notifications FOR A SPECIFIC EXTENSION once blocked".

If anyone can post here a successful workaround to in any way re-enable the normal desktop notifications for an extension (tested with Tampermonkey) after the user clicks the "block all notifications from this app" to simply reverse the decision that would be great but I think as long as this has remained unanswered makes me lean towards believing there simply is no current method and it is just a (glaring) UI bug.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly **the only method for reversing this** is to remove the extension and re-install it.

This issue has been open for nearly half a year. Not expecting a fix any time soon at this point. https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=825497

Please *star* this issue at the link above if you're affected by it.